# How to set UTF8 encoding in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have the following procedure that sends some data using utl_http

```
    procedure DoSomeThing is
      HttpRequest      utl_http.req;
      HttpResponse     utl_http.resp;      
      ResponseText     clob; 
      URL              varchar2(500) := 'https://someurl';
      PostPrameters    varchar2(30000);
    begin
      PostPrameters := 'Très cool';    
      PostPrameters := utl_url.escape(PostPrameters);      
      URL := utl_url.escape(URL,false,'UTF-8');
      
      UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8');
      HttpRequest := utl_http.begin_request(URL, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');    
      utl_http.set_authentication(HttpRequest, UserName, Password);      

      utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest,'Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
      utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Length',length(PostPrameters));
      utl_http.write_text(HttpRequest, PostPrameters);    
      HttpResponse := utl_http.get_response(HttpRequest);    
      utl_http.read_text(HttpResponse,ResponseText);   
      utl_http.end_response(HttpResponse);            
    end;
```

Data I would like to send contains some special characters : **'Très cool'**

When testing this procedure from SQL Developer, the special characters are sent properly to the server.

```
    exec DoSomeThing;  << Works great from SQL Developer
```

However the procedure is supposed to be launched from a job like:

```
    Jobname := dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name('Job_');            
    JobAction := 'begin DoSomeThing; end;';                                                               
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => Jobname, job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', job_action => JobAction, enabled => true);
```

In this case the exact same procedure dosn't send the special characters. It skips them : **'Tr?s cool'**

I guess it's because my session on SQL Developer doesn't have the same characteristics as the one in the job.

Does anyone know how to fix that please ?

Cheers,

Comment: what is the characterset of your database ??

Comment: How to get that please ?

Comment: `SQL> select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;`

Comment: From SQL Developer, it returns : AL32UTF8

Comment: I don't know if it's the same accross all the sessions

Comment: can you change UTF-8 for AL32UTF8 and try again ?

Comment: Thanks for you recommandation. Still getting the same issue though

Comment: try this: change the line `utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Length',length(PostPrameters));` by `utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Length',lengthb(PostPrameters));`. If it works, I will put the solution

Comment: Still getting "Tr?s cool" :/

Comment: but you use UTF-8 and lengthb right ?

Comment: I tried both [UTF-8 and lengthb] and [AL32UTF8 and lengthb]

Comment: `length` and `lengthb` should return the same because escaped `PostPrameters` is pure ASCII text

Comment: Maybe the string literal is not processed correctly in the background job, try replacing it with `'Tr'||chr(232)||'s cool'`.

Comment: if @WernfriedDomscheit answer does not work, you should try to get the answer in raw bytes to actually see what is inside

Comment: `'Tr'||chr(232)||'s cool'` doesn't work neither

Comment: `CHR(232)` would be the UTF-32 codepoint, i.e. on `AL32UTF8` database you will get and *"ORA-29275: partial multibyte character"*. Better use `UNISTR('\00E8')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit actually I used `chr(50088)` because my database returns 50088 for `ascii('è')`. Again when the procedure is run from SQL Developer, it works but not from a job

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

For some reason I couldn't figure out, the following method doesn't return the same result if run from SQL developer or run from a Scheduled Job. (Of course it's not specific to SQL developer but to some session paramaters)

```
utl_url.escape(PostPrameters)
```

## From my SQL developer session

**utl_url.escape('Très cool')** returns **'Tr%C3%A8s%20cool'** which works

## From Scheduled job session

**utl_url.escape('Très cool')** returns **'Tr%E8s%20cool'** which is wrong

## Solution

```
utl_url.escape(PostPrameters, false, 'UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Procedure `SET_BODY_CHARSET`:

> Sets the default character set of the body of all future HTTP requests when the media type is **text** and the character set is not specified in the Content-Type header.

Also when you declare character set `UTF-8` then you don't need to escape. You would need to escape only for ASCII or similar.

Maybe try this one:

```
PostPrameters := 'Très cool';    
URL := utl_url.escape(URL,false,'UTF-8');
  
HttpRequest := utl_http.begin_request(URL, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');    
utl_http.set_authentication(HttpRequest, UserName, Password);      

utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Type','application/text; charset="UTF-8"');
utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Length',length(PostPrameters));
utl_http.write_text(HttpRequest, PostPrameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but changing the content type to application/text results in an error.

Comment: What about `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Actually the server accepts only `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'`. Here is the equivalent of the command I need to send : `curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "Body=Très sympa" \
--data-urlencode "From=+15017122661" \
--data-urlencode "To=+15558675310" \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token`

Comment: Did you try? Mainly skip `PostPrameters := utl_url.escape(PostPrameters);`